# Capybara fill_in only works with field id, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

While runnng my rspec tests, I was getting an error
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "First Name"

My rspec test is as follows

```
 describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    puts page.body
    fill_in "First Name",   with: "Matthew"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
  end

  it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

My form view is as so

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

So after a couple hours of head bashing, I tried replacing

```
fill_in "First Name",   with: "Matthew"
```

with

```
fill_in "user_first_name",   with: "Matthew"
```

(i.e. using the field id and not the name)
My question is why does this work only with the field id ('user_first_name') and not the field name ('First Name')?

Comment: Is the label of the field actually 'First Name', not 'First name' or 'first name' or anything else? `fill_in` will work with a field ID, label, or name.

Answer (score 1):

Rails uses the `human_attribute_name` [method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name) to output the label text when you do `f.label :first_name`.

This means the text of the label is "First name", not "First Name", so that's what you'll need to provide to Capybara.