# Rspec Capybara on simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I am starting to test my app and I am stuck on the  user register form...

```
  h2 Sign up
  = simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    .form-inputs
      = f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true
      = f.input :last_name, required: true
      = f.input :nickname, required: true
      = f.input :email, required: true
      = f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length)
      = f.input :password_confirmation, required: true
    .form-actions

      =f.button :submit , class:'btn btn-primary'
```

I am following an exemple like this one:

```
describe "Signing up " do
  it "allows a user to sign up for the site and create object in the database" do
    expect(User.count).to eq(0)

    visit "/en/users/sign_up"
    expect(page).to have_content("Sign up")
    fill_in "First Name", with: "John"
    fill_in "Last Name", with: "Doe"
    fill_in "Nickname", with: "JD"
    fill_in "Email", with: "john@email.com"
    fill_in "Password", with: "password"
    fill_in "Password (again)", with: "password"
    click_button "Create User"

    expect(User.count).to eq(1)
    #

  end
end
```

I dont know how to test the simple form labels?I tried with adding an **id** to:

`= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, id: "first_name"`

and the in the spec:

`fill_in "first_name", with: "John"`

It doesn't make the job... What should I do ?

Comment: You need to look at the actual HTML that is generated for the page

Answer (score 1):

Found a hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254945/capybara-fill-in-only-works-with-field-id-why)

`fill_in "user_first_name", with: "John"` works :)